# How can I solve my asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I want to get the number of users for each shop in my database. So I'm making two call in my Db, one for the shop and another for the users. And I have a problem I don't have anything in my "nbr_users" return value.. Could you help ?

```
function nbr_users(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.User.find({
            shop: key
        }, (err, users) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else {
                resolve(users.length) // Maybe my problem is here...
            }
        })
    })
}

module.exports = (req, res) => {
    db.Account.find({},
    (err, accounts) => {
        if (err) res.json(err)
        else {
            var accountMap = {}
            var i = 0;
            accounts.forEach(async function(account) {
                accountMap[i++] = {
                    users: await nbr_users(account.key) // the value I want
                }
              });
            res.json({user_list: accountMap})
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to use .then on the promise to get the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
accounts.forEach(async function(account) {
            accountMap[i++] = {
                users: await nbr_users(account.key) // the value I want
            }
          });
```

Should be more like

```
var accountMap = {}
var i = 0;
for (let account of accounts) {
   let users = await nbr_users(account.key);
   accountMap[i++] = {
                users: users
            }
}

res.json({user_list: accountMap});
```

Make sure you're running that in an `async` function.

Downside of this way is that each subsequent `nbr_users(account.key)` request must wait for the previous one. There is a way to run them all without each one waiting for the previous as well, let me know if you want me to show that way -- it's slightly more complicated

Comment: OMG it's working ! Thank you so much ! yes I would like to see that

Comment: something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/o5y9269b/ -- you use '.map' to iterate over accounts and return a promise from each one (an async function naturally returns a promise), and then await `Promise.all` for your new list of promises.

Comment: Note - I made a typo in that, it shouldn't be `Promises.all`

Comment: That's so much fast !! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You have something returning from your `nbr_users(key)`. You have a promise, then you may use `.then`.

Because you are in a loop with async. functions and you don't want to lose track of `i` I'd recomend you to use anonymous [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

```
function(i){
    nbr_users(account.key).then(function(length){
      accountMap[i] = {
        users: length
    })
}(i++);
```